# Is it possible to load F# types using .NET/Link?

Tags: .netlink

Suppose I define a type in F# such as:

```
type person = { name: string; age: int; height: float }
  member per.growChild () = { per with age=age+1; height=height+10.0 }
```

Can I load this type in Mathematica and use the associated member methods? All of the documentation for .NET/Link refers only to C# and Visual Basic.